# Set multiple registers in a single line (Verilog)

Tags: verilog

If I have a number of registers;

```
reg a;
reg b;
reg c;
```

is it possible to set a value (1'b0) to all of them in a single line (like in C), inside an always block, like this:

```
a <= b <= c <= 1'b0;
```

or would it see the two right-most non-blocking assignment operators as less-than-or-equal-to operators and do a logic evaluation?

Or would it be possible with blocking operators?

```
a = b = c = 1'b0;
```

Comment: `{ a, b, c } = { 3'b000 };`?

Comment: @VladLazarenko Hadn't thought of that! Would it be possible with a non-blocking assignment; `{a, b, c} <= 3'b0` ?

Comment: Yes, I don't see why not.

Comment: Thanks! If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: That's fine. We'll consider it accepted :)

Comment: Perhaps a bit more general: { a, b, c } = '0;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SystemVerilog, you can do

```
{a,b,c} <= '0; // non-blocking
```

or

```
a = (b = (c = '0) ); // blocking
```

Comment: I think you meant *old* Verilog. No it won't. But most tools support this now.